# Java WebStart not working

Tags: java-8, java-web-start, intranet

I successfully ran a Java WebStart application under JDK 1.8.0_65
However the same application doesn't run under JDK 1.8.0_151
Yes, I added the URL to the Exception Site List in order to run the app under JDK 1.8.0_65
The app is 3rd party and I have no access to it, I only run it and I'm certain it hasn't changed.
I am on a company Intranet, i.e. a closed, isolated network.
The error I get is as follows:

Unsigned application requesting unrestricted access to system.
The following resource is signed with a weak signature algorithm MD5withRSA and is treated as unsigned:
http://xyz:1234/dir/res.jar.pack.gz

Cheers,
Avi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read this manual?
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml

Focus on "Applications signed with MD5withRSA or MD5withDSA"

Comment: @Pawel, I assume you are referring to the following - which appears on the page you liked to:

Application users
If you encounter either of the messages above, it is recommended that you contact the website where you are seeing this message or the application vendor and provide them with the message. The website or vendor needs to improve the security of the application, as the application is no longer secure using MD5withRSA or MD5withDSA.

So I understand that my only option is to ask the application developer to make their application more secure. Correct?

Comment: Developers should update secure during compilation but you have couple work arounds.
You can downgrade your java - unrecomended.
Sign the application by yourself
Modify your java environment

Try to look for any work around in google. There is couple solutions.

Comment: @Pawel, thank you but I was told that our company will be replacing the app with a different application so I don't need to fix the problem any more. Thank you for your help.